# how to get a file from the staging area?

Tags: git, staging

I have a file "a.txt" I do

`git add a.txt`

Now, I remove a.txt (or modify it).

Then I want that a.txt that I have added to the staging area

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `git status` has the info you're looking for:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

So, in this instance, you should run:

```
git checkout -- a.txt
```

Comment: And this really does the job.

Comment: so a `git checkout -- a.txt` gets it from the staging area

and a `git checkout HEAD a.txt` gets it from the repo

Comment: @user3571278 to be more correct, it gets it from the commit under HEAD pointer. You can provide any other pointer, absolute or relative, such as branch or tag name, commit sha1, stash, reflog and ^~ modifiers. Oh, and the remotes too.